# How does crash reporting tools on iOS desymbolicate the crash reports on a release build?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

On iOS, the Debug symbols are stripped from the release binaries for security reasons. So how does a crash reporting tool like Fabric,Hockey etc "desymbolicate" and show a nice stack trace of the crash point from a release build???

Do they capture/trace the crashes on their own, rather than relying on OS generated traces?

Comment: For Fabric you need to upload the dsym files, only after uploading this can they symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: Ok. But release build never have dsym files right, so how does it work then? Besides tools like Hockey show the symbolicated crash logs of the crashes encountered in the field i.e encountered during Beta Testing. I've personally experienced a crash as a Beta Tester and it showed up nice and fine without me ever uploading the dSym

Comment: A release build does have a dsym, I've never worked with Hockey but Fabric upload the dsym when you upload a build to there system.

Comment: Hockey also requires dSYM for symbolication, even for release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following applies to OS X, iOS, tvOS and also watchOS:

1. If binaries themselves are containing symbols, they can only provide class name and method names. But never filenames or line numbers. So their benefit is limited but the increase in binary size is big, ~30-50% bigger (estimations, can be larger or smaller depending on the app)
2. If your build settings are setup properly (default settings = `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` set to `DWARF with dSYM File`), then ever single time you do build you'll also get a dSYM package with a dwarf file that contains everything needed to symbolicate and also getting filenames and line numbers.

So how do iTunes Connect, Xcode, Fabric, HockeyApp and others actually do symbolication?

They are all using the dwarf files in the dSYM package. They take the memory address from a stack frame, find the corresponding binary image in the Binary Images section of the crash report by matching the address ranges, take the UUID of the binary image, find the dSYM package which contains the matching UUID for the matching CPU architecture and then run a tool like `atos` against it to get the (demangled) symbols.

And how do they get the stack traces?

1. The OS generates crash reports out of process which get used by iTunes Connect and Xcode.
2. All 3rd party systems need code added to the app which sets up crash handlers for signal based crashes and unhandled exceptions and at crash time try to safely fetch all information needed in a crash report. This code runs in the apps process and therefor may not do a lot of things (e.g. it may not allocate memory at crash time) to safely collect that data and not destroy any users data or cause a device deadlock. 3rd party systems can not get the system generated crash reports, because those are located outside of the apps sandboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Very detailed. I was under the assumption that release builds dont generate dsym files. But if I set **DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT** to **DWARF with dSYM File**, the dSym files get generated. But the .ipa bundle eventually does not include it for security reasons. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: The .ipa has no need for the dSYM and having it as part of the .ipa it would also be distributed to all customers via the App Store, and you definitely don't want that (depending on your stack those files can be >1GB in size).